# Function doesn't create a random sequence when it's in cycle - Pascal

Tags: pascal

My code is written on PascalABC.NET.
Function (RandomRoute) is working, but when I try to run it several times in cycle it doesn't work in a proper way. Every iteration it has to generate a new sequence.

[image: output] .

On this picture you can see what I mean. I don't understand where the problem is. 
P.S. sorry for my english

```
function RandomRoute (n : integer; a : TMatrix) : List<integer>;
var
  k,i,j,iRand, pathLength: integer;
  flag : boolean;
  tempList : List<integer> := new List<integer>;
Begin
  randomize; 
  for k := 0 to (n-1) do
  begin
    repeat
      iRand := random(0, (n-1));
      if (tempList.Contains(iRand)) then       
      begin
        flag := false;
      end
      else
      begin
        flag := true;
        tempList.Add(iRand);
      end;            
    until (flag);
  end;   

  tempList.Add(tempList[0]);    
  pathLength := 0;
  for var z : integer := 0 to (n-1) do
  begin
    i := tempList[z]; j := tempList[z+1];
    pathLength := pathLength + a[i,j];
  end;
  tempList.Add(pathLength);
  Result := tempList;
End;
```

MAIN FUNCTION

```
BEGIN
  var randRoute : List<integer> := new List<integer>;
  var minRoute : List<integer> := new List<integer>;

  routeLength := 0; 

  writeln ('City Count:');
  readln (n); 
  readln (firstcity);
  MatFullRandom(n, mass); 
  massCopy := mass;

  DispMat (n, mass);
  GreedyAlg(firstcity, n, mass);

  Writeln ('RANDOM ROUTES:');

  randRoute := RandomRoute(n, massCopy);
  minRoute := randRoute;

  for var z : integer := 0 to 10 do
  begin      
    randRoute := RandomRoute(n, massCopy);
    if (randRoute.Last < minRoute.Last) then minRoute := randRoute;
    writeln('Random Route ', randRoute);    
  end;

  writeln('The best from randomRoute: ',minRoute);

  MatrixRandomRoute(n, minRoute, massCopy, massRed);
  DispMat(n, MassRed);
  DrawGraph(n, mass); 
END.
```

Comment: Please consider marking the solution that he provided as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

The `Randomize()` function initializes the random number generator, with a number, typically derived from the system clock. Successive calls to `Randomize()` in a loop together with a call to `Random()` can yield the same result repeatedly.

Therefore, call `Randomize()` only once in the program.